# Is there a book with well sourced "discussions" on hilchos lashon hara?

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, jewish-books, lashon-hara-slander

I am looking for a book that does not simply state all of the halachis (such as Sefer Chafetz Chaim). Rather what I am looking for is a book that would do something like pose a question or case ("Someone rips you off and you want to warn a relative" or "You suspect someone is physically abusive and you want to make the local Rabbi aware") and then would give a full article on exactly how to go about speaking and or listening sourcing all of the points.
Does anyone know of such a book or article?

Comment: Hebrew or English?

Comment: I cannot recommend enough the new (Nov. 2015) book by Rabbi Daniel Z. Feldman of Yeshiva University, "[False Facts and True Rumors](http://www.amazon.com/False-Facts-True-Rumors-Contemporary/dp/1592644414)" which is brilliantly written and organized, with more well thought-out and sophisticated discussion than I've seen in any book in Hebrew (although the Nesivos Chayim Sefer Chafetz Chaim is also really good)

Comment: @Matt Thanks for that. I just picked up the book and it's fantastic. Can you tell me about the Nesivos Chayim?

Comment: it's a commentary on Sefer Chafetz Chaim, which clarifies many points, but also has a fairly long (~80 pages) appendix with short (averaging about one page each) essays on multiple topics in Hilchos Lashon Hara, including many that are relevant to reporting and journalism

Comment: @Matt Thanks, I just realized I have that sefer. It's very valuable.

Comment: @Matt Consider posting an answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are several. One of the best selling in English is probably [*Chofetz Chaim: A Daily Companion*](http://www.artscroll.com/Products/CCCH.html), published by ArtScroll Mesorah Publications.

The book goes through the laws in a format that allows for study of one Halachah or set of Halachoth as part of a daily schedule, and it gives common, practical examples drawn from real life (e.g., company staff meetings) and guides the reader through the application of the laws in the case presented.

Comment: I don't think is what the OP is looking for; the Daily Companion tells you the halakhos but doesn't have lengthy discussions of particular scenarios, it's just copying from the Sefer Chofetz Chaim

Comment: @Matt, maybe I'm thinking of a different book (though I don't think so), but it seems from the preview on the site that it gives practical examples and walks through how the laws apply in those specific instances.

Answer (score 2):

I found this on HebrewBooks.

Apparently, (Rabbi?) Shlomoh Rozner wrote two books that match your description: [Alei Be'er](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/49151) and [Shu"t LaChafetz BaChayim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/49172). He also apparently cross-references the latter book across the margin of [his edition of Chafetz Chayim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/49098).

Comment: Thank you. I went to his house today and bought the book from him.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Guard Your Tongue](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000OFT7VO) by Rabbi Zelig Pliskin. It goes through several scenarios that are very practical on hilchos lashon hara.

You could also try reading the Chapters 5, 13, 17, 19 and 21 in [Journey To Virtue: The Laws Of Interpersonal Relationships](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1578197597), by Avrohom Ehrman (ArtScroll/Mesorah, 2002).